# Command in Linux to perform opposite of egrep?

Tags: bash, shell-script, grep

I want to find which of the patterns or words are not present in file.
Example :

test.txt

```
marco 
polo
charlie 
anthony
john
```

`egrep 'marco|polo' test.txt`  will output marco and polo

But I want a command to output the word if its not present in file:

Ex : `egrep 'cindrella|daniel|polo' test.txt` should output cindrella and daniel and not polo.

Answer (score 4):

you want reverse greping.

```
printf "%s\n" cindrella daniel polo | grep -v -f test.txt
cindrella
daniel
```

where

- `-v` is reverse option
- `-f test.txt` take input list from `test.txt`

Comment: +1 To eliminate partial matches, the use of grep's `-x` flag would be worth considering, assuming both the input and the `test.txt` entries are one to a line.

Answer (score 1):

You can echo the name if grep doesn't match:

```
$ for i in cindrella daniel polo; do grep -q "$i" test.txt || echo "$i"; done
cindrella
daniel
```

`-q` quiet mode, exits after any match is found